# Copy nested folders contents to one folder recursively (terminal)

Tags: bash, filesystems, terminal, directory

I have a Wordpress upload folder that is structured using subfolders for months.

```
wolfr2:uploads wolfr$ tree .
.
|-- 2007
|   |-- 08
|   |   |-- beautifulkatamari.jpg
|   |   |-- beautifulkatamari.thumbnail.jpg
|   |   |-- beetle.jpg
|   |   |-- beetle.thumbnail.jpg
```

How do I use terminal to copy all the images recursively into another folder? I can't seem to wildcard folders like you can wildcard filenames. (e.g. *.jpg or *) (I'm on Mac OSX)

```
cp -R ./*.jpg .
```

?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This will copy all *.jpg files from the current folder to a new folder and preserve the directory structure.

```
tar cvfp `find . -name "*.jpg"` | (cd <newfolder>; tar xfp -)
```

---

To copy without preserving the directory structure:

```
cp `find . -name "*.jpg"` <newfolder>
```

Comment: I should have carlified in the OP that I want to get rid of the structure and just want all the images in a flat folder.

Comment: Darn, my backquotes around the find were left off.

Comment: This doesn't appear to work for files with spaces in their name

Answer (score 36):

Off the top of my head:

```
find . -type f -name \*.jpg -exec cp \{\} $TARGETFOLDER \;
```

If that doesn't work, comment and I'll try again, but `find` is definitely the way to go.

Comment: This is the correct answer because it works with files / folders that have spaces in their names.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above commands worked for me as such on macOS 10.15. Here's the one that worked:

```
find . -name "*.jpg" -exec cp /{/} [target folder path] \;
```