# Moving multiple files with same name and renaming them on the fly

Tags: bash, ubuntu, terminal, rename, move

I have multiple folders in my ubuntu 16.04 with pictures in them. I would like to move all pictures to one folder and rename all files with same name.

I can easily move pictures from first folder, but how do i copy pictures from rest of the folders without destroying (copying over) all existing files with same name?

Is there some handy oneliner that i could use in terminal for this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) and add sample input and expected output. For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour of the site](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

And So is not a free coding service

Answer (score 6):

[cp](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cp.1.html) has a useful option `--backup=numbered` that adds a numbered suffix to the name of a file that would otherwise be clobbered.

If you have a directory tree containing duplicate file names, then you can combine `cp` with `find` to collapse the structure. (Disclaimer: I did not test this, so please tread with caution.)

```
find $SOURCEDIR -type f -exec cp --backup=numbered '{}' $TARGETDIR \;
```

Thanks go to:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16669/copy-files-with-renaming
- [Copy nested folders contents to one folder recursively (terminal)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936187/copy-nested-folders-contents-to-one-folder-recursively-terminal)

Comment: thank you so much man, your solution worked, just that the file extension gets changed due to the numbering

Comment: macos: cp: illegal option -- -

Comment: @XiangChen `cp` in MacOS does not support `--backup`. This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27514652/cp-illegal-option-b-on-mac